# output won't print when code is ran, nasm x86

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I am trying to write a program in assembly that will add two numbers and display the output when ran, but somehow the output won't print when I run it. This is on NASM. I am very new to assembly. Any help is appreciated.

```
global _start

section .text

_start:
    mov ecx, [b]          
    mov eax, [a] 
    add ecx, eax
    mov ebx, 1
    mov edx, 2
    mov eax, 4
    int 0x80

    mov eax, 1       ; exiting program 
    mov ebx, 0
    int 0x80

section .data
    a db 4           ; first number
    b db 26          ; second number
```

Comment: `write` takes a pointer to characters in memory, not a valid.  You're doing `write(1, (void*)(a+b), 2)` so it returns `-EFAULT`.  Check `strace ./a.out`.  (Actually not `a+b` but the result of a 4-byte `memcpy` from 1-byte variables, reading past the end.)